# ResultSet getArray function not working?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, json

I'm making a system to detect if a user has donated automatically. It first takes records from a table where the column collected is set to 0, and where the username is the current users username. There is an items column, inside which is a json encoded array that contains what they should receive. I need to use the getArray function to get the json array, rather than getting it as a string.

I'm getting this error:
    java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException

Here is my code(if you notice something wrong with the json, let me know, can't test that because the getArray won't work).

```
public void checkForDonation(final Player player) throws JSONException {
    try {
        ResultSet rs = Launcher.getDBC()
                .getQuery(
                        "SELECT * FROM `rewards` WHERE `username`= '"
                                + player.getDisplayName()
                                + "' AND `completed`='0'");
        if (rs.next() == true) {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("items", rs.getArray("items"));
            } catch (org.json.JSONException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            json.put(obj);
            System.out.println(json);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: 8 questions and 0 accepted, gl getting some1 to help you..

Comment: Unrelated but probably something you should read: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Comment: what DB are you using, and what DB driver are you using to access it? java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException indicates a jdbc driver issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getArray() is by no means a method that automatically transforms a String stored in a database into a JSON array. JDBC and JSON have nothing in common.

Read [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray%28java.lang.String%29):

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of this ResultSet object **as an Array object** in the Java programming
>   language.
>
> Returns:
>    an Array object representing the **SQL ARRAY value** in the specified column

(emphasis mine)